# Concatenate Multiple Strings While Ignoring Null Values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to figure out a solution on how to concatenate strings from about 15 different options. Each result comes from a checkbox that is selected based on the state a person has lived in within a certain area.

I know how to turn the checkbox option into a text result. What I'm looking for is how to take these text results, combine them, then ignore null results so there isn't any weird spacing or formatting.

In short, if someone select 3 of the 15 results it would combine the 3 results cleanly and ignore the rest. Example would be: FL, CA, NY

Comment: `"This is my " & "Concatenated String."`

Comment: `N = Null` : `"This is a " & Nz(N,"") & "concatenated string that ignored a null value using Nz."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, of course, multiple ways that this can be achieved, and since you didn't provide any code or examples of how you are attempting to do this, I will provide two options.

**1** - You can concatenate the values using a combination of the `&` and `+` operators.

For example, let's say you have 15 checkboxes, all named similarly like chkState01, chkState02 ... through chkState15.  And for the simplicity of my sample code, let's assume that when referencing the checkbox control directly in code as `chkState01` that it will return either the 2 letter string abbreviation of the State it represents (i.e. NY) if the checkbox was checked, or it will return `Null` if the checkbox was not checked.  With that, you could get your results in 2 ways:

Option A

```
StateList = (chkState01 + ",") & (chkState02 + ",") & (chkState03 + ",") ....
```

If those 3 check boxes returned the following values

```
chkState01 = "NY"
chkState02 = Null
chkState03 = "FL"
```

Then the result of that concatenation code would be:

```
NY,FL,
```

Notice that the string ends with an extra comma (,) and always would since you can't know ahead of time how many of the checkboxes will be checked.  You would then need to trim that comma from your list before using it most likely.

Option B

```
'Create the list with a trailing comma that will need removed
Dim x as Integer
For x = 1 to 15
    StateList = StateList & (Me("chkState" & Format(x, "00")) + ",")
Next x
```

or, you could do:

```
'Create the list without a trailing comma
Dim x as Integer
For x = 1 to 15
    If Not IsNull(Me("chkState" & Format(x, "00"))) Then
        If Len(StateList) > 0 Then
            StateList = StateList & "," & Me("chkState" & Format(x, "00"))
        Else
            StateList = Me("chkState" & Format(x, "00"))
        End If
    End If
Next x
```

Notice that you can reference a control on a form by "generating" the name of that control as a string and referencing it in the `Me("yourcontrolname")` format.  This is one advantage to naming controls that are similar in a fashion that lends itself to a looping structure like this.  The `Format` command formats the number returned by `x` as a 2 digit with leading zeros `i.e. 1 becomes 01`

Further, using `&` to concatenate two items, where at least one of them is a string, will always result in a string output (Null & "S" = "S").  However, using the `+` to concatenate two items, where at least one of them is a Null, will always result in Null output (Null + "S" = Null).  Hence the checkboxes where the value returns Null does not cause additional commas to be included in the result.

**2** - You can write more complicated code to dynamically loop through the checkboxes and build the output list.

More likely, you are going to need to use additional code to determine which checkbox is which state abbreviation and to return the correct string value.  Maybe you made the state abbreviation part of the checkbox name `i.e. chkState_NY, chkState_FL` or maybe you have put the abbreviation in the `Tag` property of each checkbox.

Let's say you used special control naming `chkState_NY, chkState_FL`.  You could do the following:

```
Dim ctl as Access.Control

For Each ctl in Me.Controls
    If ctl.Name Like "chkState_??" Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then
            If Len(StateList) > 0 Then
                StateList = StateList & "," & Right(ctl.Name,2)
            Else
                StateList = Right(ctl.Name,2)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```